# Why does a PDF printed in iWork Pages 09 look crappy in Adobe Reader?

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe-reader, iwork

I use Snow Leopard at home and work and recently realized that the documents I create in iWork Pages 09 don't look good in Adobe Reader. I go about creating a regular document and 'Print' -> Save as PDF in Pages in OS X. The saved PDF file looks great in Preview in OS X but it looks pretty bad in Windows' Adobe Reader and even Adobe Acrobat in OS X.

Is there something I could do to make it look better on both platforms?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll either have to define what "look crappy" means or provide an example.

Comment: @NSD Agreed, I thought the same thing. Was going to upload some images and link in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, and you may see an improvement in the quality of the .PDF:

In Pages menu bar:

```
Share -> Export -> PDF -> Image Quality -> Best
```